# Font looks blurry on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

It just ok with chrome and opera. But it looks blurry on Internet explorer and Firefox. I researched and apply these css, but still no luck. My firefox and Internet explorer versions are up to date. I'm not using google font. Here is my styles.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham-Bold';
  src: url('../fonts/Gothambold/Gotham-Bold.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Gothambold/Gotham-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/Gothambold/Gotham-Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/Gothambold/Gotham-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/Gothambold/Gotham-Bold.svg#') format('svg');
}

body{
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
font-smooth: always;

font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

**View in firefox.**
[image]

**View in chrome**
[image]
Still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: What if you leave out the antialiased?

Comment: Then no changes at all.

Comment: I can't spot the blurriness you describe so it may be a monitor calibration issue. Firefox renders the font with a heavier weight but, if [this is the font you are using](http://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Gotham-Bold), it looks more correct than Chrome rendering.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Not a monitor calibration issue. Checked with different monitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was raised a while back (and fixed) in [this thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142).

Just to summarize...

**The cause:**

This firefox issue occurs on Macs where the option: "Use LCD font smoothing when available" (Settings > General > Use LCD font smoothing when available) is **checked**. (It is checked by default).

**Note:** From experience, this issue doesn't occur on the actual retina screen of the mac - but rather on **non-retina screens** connected to the mac.

Uncheck that option and restart firefox and you'll see the font looks fine!

**The fix:**

To overcome this for users with the above option enabled - simple add the following declaration in the body:

```
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

You'll be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: But this problem occurred on windows.

Comment: hmm if you're using windows then the property I mentioned won't help. That being said, I think I'll still leave this answer here - for the benefit of mac users :)

Comment: The funny thing is that he has shared a screenshot and the picture looks just fine in my PC (using a pretty regular Samsung LCD monitor). The overall issue is really intriguing...

Answer (score -1):

Text that appears blurry or pixelated in Firefox may be due to ClearType not being turned on if using Windows. To turn it on:

1. From the Windows search bar, search for 'Adjust ClearType Text'
2. Check the box to Turn on ClearType and click 'Next'
3. Follow the prompts to tune the ClearType settings and click 'Finish'.

I had the same issue and this worked for me. [Source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fonts-look-blurry).

Comment: [ClearType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/) isn't a browser setting.